# Conditionally use Middleware Only On Endpoints That Have Authorize Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-identity

I have writted a piece of middleware that I only want to run on Authenticated endpoints.

So Basically I want it in my implementation to only trigger when a controller or action is marked with `[Authorize]`. Any controller action that does not require authhorization should not require my middleware to trigger.

I've found the UseWhen functionality but the best i've managed is that the middleware only triggers once a user is authenticated. However if will still trigger on all endpoints after the user has signed in.

Here is my current conditional.

```
        app.UseWhen(context => context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseAutomaticallyRefreshTokenMiddleware();
        });
```

I think i just need to change that context check, but not exactly sure what to replace it with.

Comment: Looks like there are no paths to the matched controller at this point in the app setup. You could create a custom Controller like `RefreshingController` and mark it `Authorize`, then derive your controllers from `RefreshingController` instead. You'd implement the `OnActionExecuting` method to refresh the token there.

Comment: `OnActionExecuted` is the correct method to override.

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? And why couldn’t you put a conditional in your middleware that skips the middleware logic if the user is signed in?

Comment: Thanks for your input so far saarrrr and theMayer.

Just to give you some context. I'm using an OIDC hybrid flow with a refresh token. If a user is on an endpoint that requires authorization this piece of middleware checks the access token in the current session. If it is near to expiry this middleware does a back channel refresh token request. This only needs to trigger on authorised endpoints. Public endpoints should not run this middleware, as a user might not have signed in yet and it will start returning 401s for public endpoints if the expected tokens are not yet present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The middlewares get registered to the pipeline based on the condition and the registrations are done only at startup. The registrations are not modified afterwards. Once they are a part of the pipeline, they are a part of the pipeline. One thing you can do is to customize the Authorize attribute. Inherit the Authorize attribute, and then inside that run the logic you are running inside your middleware.

Comment: Hi Shazad thanks, for your input. I think your suggestion might be the way to go in my case given the order of the pipeline as you describe it. I will leave this open till tomorrow to get any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 enables this with endpoint routing, this can't be accomplished before that because routing decisions and endpoint selection happens much later than when the middleware pipeline runs.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could try `IActionFilter` instead of middleware.

1. `TokenRefrehFilter`

   ```
   public class TokenRefrehFilter : IActionFilter
   {
       public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
       {
       }

       public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
       {
           //check whether action is authorized attribute
           var isAuthorizedAction = context.Filters.Any(f => f.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizeFilter));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `TokenRefrehFilter`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options => {
       options.Filters.Add(typeof(TokenRefrehFilter));
   })
   SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   ```

   For this way, `TokenRefrehFilter` will run for controller request, and you could check `isAuthorizedAction` with `True` for the action needs to refreh the token.